# Must parameter binding be safer (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making PHP-code, and use database, MySql.
I wonder about parameter binding, and here is an example with a field (pw) excluded;

If the user sends a username via form, and it comes as POST

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
```

and then is used to log in;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
```

then

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
```

Has there been any protection? I mean compared to using the POST variable directly.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference whether you use:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
```

or

```
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);
```

They both contain the same value, and binding them to the parameter is exactly the same.

The protection comes from binding the parameter with a prepared statement, not the choice of variable to bind it to.

Comment: Yes, I meant that, does it make any differance from using a raw sql query instead of binding.

Comment: Yes, definitely. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=2|37.5876